# Understanding a quite basic urn problem

Tags: combinatorics

> We have an urn which contains $n$ balls numbered $1$ through $n$. Draw
> $k$ times in succession a ball and each time note its number. The
> result obtained is a sample of size $k$. Calculate the number of all
> samples  if the samples are ${\bf ordered}$ and the selection is with
> ${\bf replacement}$

### Thought:

We have $n$ balls. Let's list them: $b_1,b_2,...,b_n$. We are picking $b_{i_1},...,b_{i_k}$ balls and some of them may be the same since we are picking them with replacement.

Let's suppose for the moment that $n=4$ and $k=3$ then $(b_1,b_2,b_3)$ and $(b_1,b_3,b_4)$ are two possible samples, and $(b_1,b_1,b_1)$ is another one. Notice that ${4 \choose 3} = 4$ is all the samples for which the numbers in the list are different. So, if all we need to do this sample all the lists of the form $(b_i,b_i,*), (b_i,*,b_i), (*,b_i,b_i)$ and $(b_i,b_i,b_i)$ and there are $3\cdot4 = 12 $ such lists. In total we have $16$ possible samples for this case.

Now for the general case. We have ${ n \choose k }$ samples for lists with no repetitions. So, we need to add to this number, the list in which we have repetitions: We can subdivide this in $n-1$ cases because repetitions can occur as pairs, or trios, or fours, etc:

for pairs, for example, lists of the form $(b_i,b_i,*,*,...,*)$, we have $P(2,n) = \frac{n!}{(n-2)!}$ of them. Similarly, for trios, we have $P(3,n) = \frac{n!}{(n-3)!}$ and so on. In total we have

$$ n \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{n!}{(n-i)!} $$

where we have multiplied by $n$ because we have $n$ balls.

Conclusion. Number of possible samples:

$$ {n \choose k} + n \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{n!}{(n-i)!} $$

Is this a correct reasoning?

Comment: Could you explain how you're interpreting the "samples are ordered" part of the question? At different places, it seems as if you're using a different interpretation.

Comment: in the sense that for example $(b_1,b_2,b_3)$ is different than $(b_1,b_3,b_2)$.

Comment: in my book: "If the order of recording the k drawn numbers is essential, we say that the sample is ordered"

Comment: Why isn't it just $n^k?$  There are $n$ choices for each of $k$ draws.

Comment: There are lists with repetitions apart from $(b_i,b_i,\ldots)$, for instance $(b_1,b_2,b_1)$. Also your method neglects lists like $(b_1,b_1,b_2,b_2)$. Finally, there is a very simple and straightforward solution.

Comment: @JimmySabater In that case, where did this claim come from: "Notice that ${4 \choose 3} = 4$ is all the samples for which the numbers in the list are different."? That would make sense if the only allowed samples are 123, 124, 134, and 234, but you're considering many more samples than that. For example, 132.

Comment: n^k how come? The samples are taken with replacement which means that each time you take a ball, it is not put back in the urn

Comment: @Neymar I always thought that "with replacement" means you do always replace the ball....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the number of samples is just $n^k$: at the end we can have any $k$-sequence of values from a set of size $n$. So, to be clear, $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ count as different outcomes, e.g. This is how I interpret it when you say the results are ordered.

The unordered results with replacements are bit trickier: each such sample can be coded uniquely by a tuple of $(x_1,\ldots,x_n$ where each $x_i$ is an integer $\ge 0$ and $x_i$ counts the number of times we have ball $i$ in the sample. So the restriction is $x_1 +\ldots + x_n =k$ (we have a total of $k$ balls). By the [stars and bars method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) we count that amount as $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$. Also see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1677379/4280) for an explanation.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I completely misunderstood. I was doing the case for unordered. This was my intended question. In such case, my answer still works?

Comment: @JimmySabater No then you have the number of $k$-elements *multisets* from $n$ elements which is $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$. Quite a different problem.

Comment: How can I see that? Actaully, I got this:

$$ {n \choose k} + \sum_{i=2}^k i! {k \choose i } $$

Comment: because ${n \choose k}$ counts the samples unordered and without repetition. Now, all we need to do is add to ${n \choose k}$ the ktupes with repetition. So for example, tuples of the form $(b,b,*,*,...,*)$ we count them in $2! {k \choose 2}$ ways and so on

Comment: @JimmySabater I updated the answer to also cover the unordered case.